# Android image editing using Canvas class

Tags: android, canvas, sdk, android-image, emoji

I have done with below points in image editing using canvas:

1. Created canvas for editing image using selected image bitmap.
2. Also done with adding text,rectangle,oval and line using `drawRect()` like Canvas function.
3. Also done with saving that edited image of canvas on external storage.

So I have below problems:

1. How I can add/draw emoji on canvas?
2. How I can give the event like zoom in/out,rotate and drag anywhere to added text/oval/emoji on canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe image editor [**SDK.**](https://developers.aviary.com/)

[image]

Comment: Is this sdk free?Reason to ask this is it's now Adobe's product and I can sees pricing tag on the Creative SDK site, but there is no price details listed.